# Azure Blob Storage functions suddenly giving 403 errors

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I wrote an api endpoint to get a saskey for an Azure blob using javascript a few months ago. It's worked fine since then. Just yesterday, it started giving me 403 errors. I hadn't touched the file in months, nor had I accessed my Azure account to make changes. Looked at some posts here and checked my firewall (correctly configured), date on PC is correct, even tried resetting and using my access key2. Still getting the same error.
Azure is responding with a saskey, it's just not valid. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this would be much appreciated. Code is as follows:

api.js (mediaLoc is the file name):

```
app.get("/getSASKey", checkAuth, async function (req, res) {
  var mediaLoc = req.query.mediaLoc;
  console.log('mediaLoc is: ', mediaLoc)
  blobResult = await bloboperations.sasKey(mediaLoc).then((result) => {
  console.log('api about to send sasKey back as: ', result)
      res.send(result);
  });
});
```

bloboperations.sasKey:

```
async function sasKey(mediaLoc) {
    try {
    console.log('starting sasKey in bloboperations mediaLoc:', mediaLoc)
    var storage = require("@azure/storage-blob")
    const accountname = process.env.BLOB_ACCT_NAME;
    const key = process.env.BLOB_KEY;
    const cerds = new storage.StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountname,key);
    const blobServiceClient = new storage.BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountname}.blob.core.windows.net`,cerds);
    const containerName="dev";
    const client =blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)
    const blobName=mediaLoc;
    const blobClient = client.getBlobClient(blobName);
    const blobSAS = storage.generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
      containerName, 
      blobName, 
      permissions: storage.BlobSASPermissions.parse("racwd"), 
      startsOn: new Date(),
      expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400)
    },
    cerds 
  ).toString();
    const sasUrl= blobClient.url+"?"+blobSAS;
    return sasUrl
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

**EDIT/ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**
As soon as I posted this edit, I thought I saw space in the URL. After looking more closely and copying it to notepad, I see there isn't a space after all. Too bad, I was hoping it could be that easy!

The saskey I'm getting back from Azure is:

```
sv=2020-06-12&st=2021-07-25T20%3A58%3A53Z&se=2021-07-25T21%3A00%3A20Z&sr=b&sp=racwd&sig=q6ylvdvxFKuR1zHmK2sa%2FwjlDjRoqtA6Jt47vZ0pQt4%3D
```

I'm appending that to: `https://MYACCTHERE.blob.core.windows.net/dev/0f0djx0dshmp316324a060040a9b1624826368094.jpg?`
(0f0djx0dshmp316324a060040a9b1624826368094.jpg is the blob name on Azure.)

to get the url:

```
https://s4udev.blob.core.windows.net/dev/0f0djx0dshmp316324a060040a9b1624826368094.jpg?sv=2020-06-12&st=2021-07-25T20%3A58%3A53Z&se=2021-07-25T21%3A00%3A20Z&sr=b&sp=racwd&sig=q6ylvdvxFKuR1zHmK2sa%2FwjlDjRoqtA6Jt47vZ0pQt4%3D
```

(Obviously, this is from yesterday so it is expired.) At the time I generated it, I tried  copying and pasting this directly into the browser address line with the same 403 error.

I'm using Vue2 on the front end. The url is passed to Vue as variable sasKey and placed on the page using this code:

```
  <v-img 
  class="white--text align-end imageTag"
  max-width="10rem"
  height="100%"
  :src="sasKey"
  >
  </v-img>
```

Comment: I am not sure about the code and shooting WAY into dark here..But may be it’s returning a SAS key stripped off a special character? May be something did change on Azure password policy recently. Have you ensured that’s not a possibility?

Comment: SouravA, thank you for the suggestion. The problem is that I don't know how to troubleshoot this. MS sends back a response that looks exactly like a sasKey even if there's a problem. My understanding is that they do that so that hackers can't tell what's good or bad. Problem is, neither can I! Do you have any ideas on how I can verify the sasKey?

Comment: Use azure storage explorer and the connect via SaaS key option to verify

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SAS URL (replace just the account name with a random string) and the code where you’re using this SAS URL. I answered a similar question just yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68510129/unable-to-download-azure-blob-from-java) and wanted to see if you’re facing same issue as faced by OP in that question.

Comment: Gaurav, I read the other post and decided to just try encoding it. Worked!! Can't believe I didn't come across this problem until now. You have been really helpful to me on all my Azure blob storage issues. Can't tell you how much I appreciate it. Just checked out your profile. Maybe one day my app will sell and I can pay you back by using your Azure management tool. :)  Thank you for the quick response. Not sure of the stackoverflow protocol. I could input the answer to close out the question. But you should get the credit for the answer. Do you want to post an answer so I can vote for it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer for me was found in the comments by Gaurav Mantri. I used url encode and it fixed the problem.